# Question and answer not readable

Tags: bug, android-app

If I scroll from an answer back to the question the questions text isn't visible any more:

[image: blank post]

After scrolling it again the text appears partially:

[image: now you see me, partially]

Sometimes the answer will appear with a very small font:

[image: compressed, physically]

Source code doesn't appear in full width neither:

[image: not enough space]

and when I scroll, the grey background covers the source code completely:

[image: now you don't see me - the code]

This makes the app totally unusable.

Galaxy S2, Android 4.0.3. App version 1.0.51

Comment: Sorry about the lack of response here, I'm the only full-time dev on the app and I was on vacation. I'm looking into this, there have been similar issues reported on other <4.4 Samsung devices.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi OK, I see. Why don't you hire me as a second dev then? :)

Comment: I'd rather you just get a device that's 4.4+ ;) Dealing with WebViews back when they were WebKit vs Chromium is a mess.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Well this worked fine in previous versions so I thought it could be easy to fix.

Comment: I've done a lot of hacky fixes for this but it's due a bigger issue (the GPU in most Samsung devices can't really handle hardware acceleration mixed with WebViews)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi So I'm out of luck?

Comment: I'm going to look into it, we recently cleaned up a lot of the interface that should allow me to remove most of our hacks and see if I can find an actual fix. It might just end up being "On Samsung devices <4.4, don't enable hardware acceleration"

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can award the bounty?

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt Please note that if a fixed bug arises again, SE prefers that users file new bug reports instead of removing the [tag:status-completed] tag on the older one, and for such new reports to not be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: The dupe target was marked status-completed in March of 2015; this question was asked in October of 2014. So at the time it was asked, it was a dupe.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ah, didn't notice. Dupe voted.